# open up action on longpress of list in react native

Tags: react-native

just like in the gmail app I need help when user longpress on certain mail in inbox the message will be highlight followed by a pop up on the header contain bin icon archive and other option how do I do it

so far I displayed only the list using a map and I added each pressable

```js
<Pressable onPress={() => {}}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', width: widthP || width, borderBottomWidth: 2 }}>
    {
      item.components.map((comp, componentIndex) => {
        return getComponent({
          item: {
            ...comp, key: `${item.key}[${index}].${comp.key}`,
            watchKeys: getWatchKeys(index, item, comp),
          },
        }, b[componentIndex], heightP || height, control, setValue, getValues);
      })}
  </View>
</Pressable>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for [onLongPress](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onlongpress) as doc:

> Called if the time after onPressIn lasts longer than 500 milliseconds. This time period can be customized with delayLongPress

Comment: ya thanks for the help I did use onLongPress but I still need a lot of other functionalities like the gmail and whatsapp type methods